# EasyUI Jquery get value from selected option

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select options like this:

```
<th>Departure Transport</th>
<td><select id="departuretransport" class="easyui-combobox" data-options="required:true,prompt:'-Select-',value:''">
                <option value="P">Private Transportation</option>
                <option value="Y">York Mills</option>
                <option value="H">Highway 9</option>
                <option value="S">Sheryway Gardens</option>
                <option value="B">Barrie</option>
                <option value="D">Day Bus</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

but unable to get value from selected option like this:

```
var dp = $('#departuretransport option:selected').val();
var rp = $('#returntransport option:selected').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        data : {
                            dp : dp,
                            rp : rp,
```

Find a solution: add "valueField: 'id' in data-option

```
<td><select id="returntransport" class="easyui-combobox" data-options="valueField: 'id',required:true,prompt:'-Select-',value:''">
                <option value="P">Private Transportation</option>
                <option value="Y">York Mills</option>
                <option value="H">Highway 9</option>
                <option value="S">Sheryway Gardens</option>
                <option value="B">Barrie</option>
                <option value="D">Day Bus</option>
        </select>
```

then get value like this:

```
    var dp = $('#departuretransport').combobox('getValue');
    var rp = $('#returntransport').combobox('getValue');
```

Comment: $('#departuretransport').val();

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML This returns empty value. I guess it is because class="easyui-combobox"

Comment: There seems to be another library (probably EasyUI) that has overridden the general behavior of your dropdown list. I advise using that library the way it was intended (surely *it* has a way to retrieve the selected value of a dropdown).

Comment: Honestly I dont know what you did and do exactly. So this is how it should work. So if it doesnt try to find out why.

Comment: @Colin: If you found an answer, please post it as an answer instead of editing it into your questions. After a while you can accept one of your own answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a solution: add "valueField: 'id' in data-option

Private Transportation
                York Mills
                Highway 9
                Sheryway Gardens
                Barrie
                Day Bus

then get value like this:

```
                var dp = $('#departuretransport').combobox('getValue');
                var rp = $('#returntransport').combobox('getValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

i simulated your code on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agLcypbj/) but cannot repoduce your problem.

```
$('#departuretransport')
.on('change', function(){
    // duplicate selector for simulating problem
    alert($('#departuretransport option:selected').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use it like this

```
var dp = $('#departuretransport').val();
var rp = $('#returntransport').val();
```